# Project object existence boolean in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document structure that looks like this (two example docs below).

```
{
  "A": "value"
},
{
  "A": "value",
  "B": {
    "a": "value",
    "b": "value"
  }
}
```

I want to aggregate such that the value of field `A` is projected while a `true/false` value is returned depending on whether the object `B` exists. The result of the query would be:

```
{
  "A": "value",
  "B": false
},
{
  "A": "value",
  "B": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even a shorter solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
   $project: {
      A: 1,
      B: { $cond: ["$B", true, false] }
   }
})
```

or

```
db.collection.aggregate({
   $project: {
      A: 1,
      B: { $ifNull: [{ $toBool: "$B" }, false] }
   }
})
```

However, following documents will yield different result than the other answers. Check your application if such documents apply.

```
{
   'A': 'value5',
   'B': false
},    
{
   'A': 'value5',
   'B': []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "B": {
      "$cond": [
        { "$eq": ["$B", undefined] },
        false,
        true
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/index.html) operator:

> If the argument is a field that is missing in the input document, $type returns the string "missing".

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      A: 1,
      B: {
        $ne: [
          {
            $type: "$B"
          },
          "missing"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SodczMQ5Vev)